# Erro ao converter inteiro nulo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou fazendo uma conversão de um valor `int`:

`int.Parse(detalhe.GANO_ID_ATIV.ToString())`

Porém está me dando um erro

```
A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.
```

O que poderia estar causando?

Comment: E qual é o conteúdo da `detalhe.GANO_ID_ATIV`

Comment: está vindo null...

Comment: @ArthurMoraes, fora as respostas de outras perguntas. Se no caso esta propriedade do objeto têm a possibilidade de vir número ou `null`, se faz interessante utilizar `Convert.ToInt32(detalhe.GANO_ID_ATIV.ToString())`, pois ele trata situações vindo `null` retornando como `0`, logo o `int.Parse` ele cai em `exception` nesses casos. (Apenas um resumão do que utilizar de acordo com a regra da sua programação)

Comment: nao amigo, continuou dando o mesmo erro.... nem com int.Parse e nem com Convert.ToInt32